# trying to use ahax to get the values as array and assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Writing ajax call which is fairly simple, but i am trying to use the ajax call to get the values as an array and store in a variable for use

like this :

```
var fields = ['address', 'inventory', 'catogory', 'city', 'country', 'customer', 'sales_by_store'];
```

wrote my ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "page.cfm",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res); // I am returning array from the query
        }
    });
```

but not sure how i show in the jquery array as above and assign to a variable

Comment: Can you show te result in console log?

Comment: yes sure, the console log. appearing just like the above array